# why are coin flips a Markov process?

Tags: probability, statistics

from wikipedia (if you say it's false I believe you):

> A series of independent states (for example, a series of coin flips)
> satisfies the formal definition of a Markov chain. However, the theory
> is usually applied only when the probability distribution of the next
> state depends on the current one

by definition, the next coin flip should depend on the current one, no?

Comment: You believe that the next outcome of a coin toss depends on the prior one as a matter of definition?

Comment: not prior one but the current one

Comment: If you want you can have two states $\{H,T\}$ with transition probabilities $1/2$ and $1/2$ between them. Of course, regardless of which state we are in, we will be in the H state next with prob 1/2.

Comment: so then since it's independent of the current state, it's not a Markov process?